# Block display bug in IE 6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

Does any one know why the block in top-right corner of [the page](http://preview.hksenet.hk) look different in IE6?  How to fix it?

Comment: Not very many of us are going to have IE 6.   Can you describe the problem or provide a screenshot?

Comment: IE6 ? Nobody use IE6 no more :http://www.modern.ie/ie6countdown. FFS, throw your computer away.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have ie6 here also however looking at it through ie7 display mode there was an issue with the searchContainer being bigger than the rest of the block which may be what you are seeing.

Adding height:45px may fix the issue.

Hope this is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

IE6 doesn't natively support opacity in png images, and has some problems with z-ordering but both issues can be worked around.

Put this css:

```
#pageheader { z-index:999; }
#logo { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
            src='http://preview.hksenet.hk/Content/images/HKSE_logo_2C.png'); }
#logo img { filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0); }
```

into a stylesheet and include that into your page using a conditional comment for IE6 only.